# Difference between a "crowned jewel", "crown jewel", and "jeweled crown"?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation-vs-spelling, eggcorn

I was grading a student's paper and found their use of the term **crowned jewel** confusing. They used the term in this way:

> The article was the *crowned jewel* of their evidence..

It sounded wrong at first, but when I say it out loud, I sense that I have heard it said that way before.

However, shouldn't they really write: "The article was *the crown jewel* of their evidence." or "The article was *a crown jewel* of their evidence."

A jewel that was "crowned" would be one that has a crown put on it. And a jewel that is part of a crown (or in the crown) would be a "crown jewel". This would be the singular form signifying one of only a handful of very special items. And a "jeweled crown" would be the crown that is lavishly decorated. Finally, I suppose a "crowning jewel" would be a jewel (or special item) that is shown as a singular demonstration of one's significance.

**Main question**: **Is the above-mentioned use of "crowned jewel" the wrong spelling for the term that describes an item of special value?** My intuition is to help them correct their spelling.

Secondary question: Am I correct about the definitions of the other variations of "crown" and "jewel"?

Comment: Yes,  it ought to be "crown jewel." I agree with all your definitions.

Comment: It's an eggcorn; *crown jewel* and *crowned jewel* sound exactly the same in English. So if you just learned the expression by hearing it ...

Comment: It's either an [eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) or a [malapropism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) I would argue that it falls under both categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your analysis, the student's original phrase probably derived from a mis-hearing of

> crown jewel or crown jewels

In the UK we would naturally think of the Crown Jewels (plural) normally held in the Tower of London; the ceremonial regalia of the monarch including some jeweled crowns, but also swords, orbs and spoons - note not specifically individual jewels.

More generally the Crown Jewels (plural) of an organisation are their most prized possessions.

Your student's use of the singular Crown Jewel moves away from the idea of a collection of valuable things. Crown Jewel (singular) does occur in dictionaries, with the meaning of a single jewel that is part of the monarch's regalia. I see it as a slight stretch to use Crown Jewel in the way your student, but I do think it works.

In other contexts we might say

> The Crowning Glory

but that seems inappropriate when talking about evidence, and doesn't quite have the same meaning.

Comment: The student wrote **crowned jewel** which has yet another different meaning from that of *crown jewels*, and *crown jewel*.

Comment: Mari-Lou, yes they wrote that, but as I and others have speculated it is probably a mis-hearing of crown jewels; if you said either crown jewels or crowned jewels quickly they sound very similar.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *crowned jewel* is probably a mishearing of *Crown jewel*. But that phrase, though not unknown, is itself slightly peculiar: the Crown Jewels, particularly in Britain, are the collection owned by the Royal Family, and so presumably the best in the country. There is, though, no singular Crown Jewel. The only sensible related phrase is *the jewel in the crown*, which gained currency in the 19th century, as referring to India being the brightest treasure in the British Empire.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic: the Crown Jewels are not owned by the royal family. They are owned by the British State and worn by the Queen in her capacity as Head of State.

Comment: LOL! A *pedant* is always **too** pedantic! As an American, I may have falsely assumed that the State and the Royal Family of Britain are joined at the hip. According to the OED the singular crown jewel is defined as "A particularly valuable or prized possession or asset:"

Comment: I don't know, @ScotM - I personally strive for a working balance between being too pedantic and being just pedantic enough. :-)

Comment: That should be a wink, @Little Eva, ***excessively*** concerned about detail is the definition! It is a matter of opinion what level of concern for detail pushes you over the line to pedantic. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The terms 'crown jewel' or 'crown jewels' are more often used in a figurative sense in the context of honoring something / someone for its / one's exemplary or glorious stature.

> Sachin, the crown jewel of Indian cricket team, has announced retirement from one-day internationals.